# Can you access a single input that has been asked multiple times

Tags: python, for-loop, input

```
N = int(input("Upišite broj od 1 do 50: "))
X = int(input("Upišite broj od 1 do 10: "))

for i in range(1, N+1):
    Zg = int(input("Upišite broj od 1 do 9: "))
    Zi= int(input("Upišite broj od 1 do 9: "))

if Zi == Zg:
```

Since the `Zg` and `Zi` variables will be assigned a value multiple times, what is the best way store those values to access later? How can I do this without making extra 50 variables?

EDIT: Don't mind the second language. What I want to do is to access just one  input.

Comment: Look up what `list`s are

Comment: This is extremely unclear. Do you want to access the value of `Zg` from a previous iteration? Or collect the values from all the iterations and process them all? How?

Comment: I know what lists are but how can they even help me here?

Answer (score 2):

*(You ought to follow the [PEP8 guide](https://pep8.org/#naming-conventions) to name variables: use lower case).*

If you want to check the variables after each entry, you need to put the `if` condition inside the loop, for instance:

```py
n = int(input("Upišite broj od 1 do 50: "))

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    zg = int(input("Upišite broj od 1 do 9: "))
    zi = int(input("Upišite broj od 1 do 9: "))
    if zi == zg:
        print("Brojevi su jednaki")  # google translated ;-)
```

If you put the `if` condition after the `for` loop, you only evaluate the last entry. Note that the `zg` and `zi` variable may not be initialised (if `n` is 0).

```py
n = int(input("Upišite broj od 1 do 50: "))

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    zg = int(input("Upišite broj od 1 do 9: "))
    zi = int(input("Upišite broj od 1 do 9: "))

if zi == zg:  # <- check only the last values
    print("Brojevi su jednaki")  # google translated ;-)
```

If you want the user to enter the values and then check it afterward, you need to store the values in a list. For instance, you can store the couples `(zg, zi)`:

```py
n = int(input("Upišite broj od 1 do 50: "))

entries = []
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    zg = int(input("Upišite broj od 1 do 9: "))
    zi = int(input("Upišite broj od 1 do 9: "))
    entry = zg, zi
    entries.append(entry)

# check the entries
for i, (zg, zi) in enumerate(entries, 1):
    if zi == zg:
        print(f"{i}: Brojevi su jednaki: {zg} == {zi}")
```

Here is an example of execution:

```
Upišite broj od 1 do 50: 2
Upišite broj od 1 do 9: 4
Upišite broj od 1 do 9: 6
Upišite broj od 1 do 9: 2
Upišite broj od 1 do 9: 2
2: Brojevi su jednaki: 2 == 2
```

Comment: Thank you and i used upper case because its a school thing and i have to enter the exact variable name.